# Newly created class Culture Info varies from Home controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have created a new class for my services model with DateTime? variables to be used in my main Controller which looks like this

```
public class DateRange
{

    public DateTime? StartUtc { get; set; }

    public DateTime? EndUtc { get; set; }

    public DateTime? ExceptUtc { get; set; }

}
```

In controller i am calling the class like this

```
var DateTest = new DateRange();

DateTest.StartUtc
```

But the issue is my controller culture info is de-De but the newly created class culture info seems to be en-US. I can't get why this is happening. My whole applications default culture info is set to de-DE. 'DateTest.StartUtc' seems to be taking the entered date format as en-US. Can anyone explain or understand why this is happening?

Comment: A DateTime is stored as a number in UTC.  So your VS settings may just be set to en-US.  The VSW settings is just the way the DateTime is being displayed and does not mean that anything is wrong.  VS will automatically convert the DateTime to a string so you can read value.

Comment: @jdweng sorry for the noob question, does VS mean visual studio? if so what's VSW settings?

Comment: VS is Visual Studio.  VSW was a typo.  Should be VS.  See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/configure-international-settings-in-windows?force_isolation=true#prepare-keyboards-time-zones-and-other-regional-settings

Comment: @jdweng thanks for the clarification. But my winsystemlocale is de-DE and only this specific class is renderinng en-US. I will check where the error might be, thanks again